# "Police say there appear to be signs of a break-in." Why "appear" instead of "appears"?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, modal-verbs

Here is an example:

> Police say there appear to be signs of a break-in.

I wonder why *appears* was not used instead of *appear* in the preceding sentence. Can linking verbs function as modal verbs?

Comment: This is not a case of linking or modal verbs. This is a case of [_There_-Insertion](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/149513/15299). The subject is _signs of a break-in_, which is plural. That's where the _appear_ comes from.

Comment: @JohnLawler: What's the there-insertion got to do with it? "Signs" is clearly the subject any way you scramble it. "Signs of a break-in appear to be there." "Signs of a break-in appear to be in evidence." Sheesh. All these _rules_.

Comment: sorry, I just noticed that my example hasn't got anything with my question, but can't a linking verb function as a modal one?

Comment: You should edit your question so it has an example...even if the example is incorrect...that way we can discuss it.

Comment: @Ricky so what happens if you remove "there" from the sentence?

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Didn't I just say "Signs of a break-in appear to be in evidence." No "there" anywhere, while the meaning is still the same. I don't believe in "there-insertion." Half the time folks insert "there" because they're lazy and don't wish to be bothered. You'll recall Kierkegaard: "People demand freedom of speech as a compensation for the freedom of thought which they seldom use."

Comment: @Ricky Kierkegaard said some cool things but he was a real jerk in real life...that aside, I agree with the quote, and that aside, your alternative sentence changes the meaning of the original...it sounds weird, anyway...weird in a "huh?" way.

Comment: @Ricky The professor has a point...check out the link he posted...it's cool stuff.

Comment: @michael_timofeev: Meh ... I looked at it. It's "too much of a good thing." You can't make up a rule for every trifle. As Pushkin's hero put it, or didn't, "Harmony cannot be verified by algebra," or something to that effect. Had Puccini followed every damn rule of composition, verismo would not have become a genre.

Comment: @JohnLawler Hmm, isn't the Subject *there*?

Comment: @Ricky You've got your *there*s mixed up!

Comment: *PLEASE DON'T MOVE THIS FANTASTIC SYNTAX QUESTION TO ELL!!!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, linking verbs are different from modals in English grammar, though there may very well be an historical connection.  The modals in current English have very special grammatical properties, one of which is inversion in questions: "May/Should/Will/.. I show you my portrait?"  But you can't invert linking verbs.

Your example has been a puzzle for grammarians,

> Police say there appear to be signs of a break-in.

because "appear" seems to agree in number with "signs", even though "signs" can't possibly count as subject of "appear".  An artificial solution to this is to suppose that "there" can have plural number, even though it has no plural ending, and in

> There are signs of a break-in.

the "there" is the subject and is plural, with "are" agreeing with plural "there".  "Appear" takes a sentence complement as subject, and it undergoes a transformation Subject-Raising-to-Subject so that the plural "there" becomes the subject of "appear" which then agrees in number with this plural subject.  That's why "appear" shows plural agreement.  (I don't think anyone really likes this analysis.)