# There was vs. was

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adverbs

Recently, a native English speaker (I'm not) suggested I'd improve a sentence of mine by removing a superfluous *there*:

> Against the wall **there** was a yellow bicycle.

This made me think: is there any case where a sentence structured like `<where> there was <something>` requires the *there* to be... there? Or can it be safely omitted in any of these sentences?

Some examples:

> 1. On his face **there** was a silly smile.
> 2. On the floor **there** were two tiny earrings.
> 3. On his back **there** was a disgusting mole.

Comment: The "there" you're asking about is not so much superfluous as optional, by which I mean the "there" can be omitted in your sentence about bicycles, and in example sentences 1, 2, and 3, if you wish; or you can include the "there" if you wish, however, for reasons of emphasis, or your personal style.  You might want to make "there" the first word in each of those sentences, and place the introductory phrase ("against the wall", or "on his face/the floor/his back") at the end, but that's up to you.

Comment: [_There_-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/149513/15299) also works for locative verbs, and with a preposed locative phrase, is equally optional: _In the sunlight (there) stood a statue of Mickey Mouse_. But it's obligatory with some verbs, like _seem_: _There seems to be a problem_ but not *_To be a problem seems_ or *_A problem seems to be._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a stylistic choice. Your friend thought it sounded, or read, better without *there*. Others might not agree. The word can be safely omitted in your three sentences as, presumably, it is functioning as existential there; on the other hand, *there*, both in the original sentence and in the other three can be locative there, which plays a different function (something like *over there*) and requires another stylistic choice as to whether to include it. Those in favour of including it in any instance may not agree that concision is always the best style.

For the locative use, the sentence would not (if the writer so chose) be punctuated as

> 1 Against the wall, there was a yellow bicycle.

but as

> 2 Against the wall, there, was a yellow bicycle.

Note these punctuations are not necessary punctuations in either case; they are just meant to bring out the differences in (1) existential there and (2) locative there.

Comment: I would have given this a +1 anyway for the examples of punctuation, but *existential* and (especially) *locative* had me smiling.